# "Хотя(,) если ..., то" в начале предложения.

Tags: синтаксис

***Хотя(,) если** подумать**, то** может быть.*
***Хотя(,) если** предположить, что он не врет, **то** история поучительная.*

Что-то категорически не хочется мне ставить тут запятую. А почему - не соображу. Вроде бы "если .., то" тут подчиненное. Нет?
Может, сама форма предложения с "хотя" в своем начале некорректна?

Answer (score 2):

Хотя если подумать, то (это) может быть. Хотя если предположить, что он не врет, то история поучительная.

Уступительный союз ХОТЯ имеет присоединительный характер и относится ко всему предложению.

Правило

Запятая не ставится при встрече   двух подчинительных союзов, если  придаточное нельзя переставить. А сделать это бывает невозможно по разным причинам, в частности, при наличии двойных союзов  (ЕСЛИ...ТО).

Примечание

Для присоединительных союзов действует свое правило: обычно нет запятых после союзов А, И, а для союза НО - авторское решение.

И едва я вступил на опушку леса, как сразу наткнулся на кабанов. А когда взошло солнце, пред нами открылся вид на снеговую вершину. Но, как ни мы ни старались, дойти до  устья реки в этот день нам так и не удалось. Но если противнику удавалось отбить атаку, пехота вновь шла в наступление.

Поэтому поле союза ХОТЯ в присоединительном значении может быть авторское решение, если следующий после него подчинительный союз  не двойной. В случае  двойного союза запятая не ставится.

Comment: Это ближе, но все еще недостаточно.  
1. "Хотя" - союз, как вы сами сказали, имеет присоединительный характер, т.е. является союзом ***сочинительным***.  
2. Если "то" убрать, то запятая появится? Есои судить по нацкорпусу, то это совершенно не очевидно. Там много примеров, привожу один.  
  
Хотя если знакомые, большого ума благородные доны, желая отрекомендовать меня лестным образом, представляли как «лучшего русского писателя Эстонии», мне оставалось только раздраженно пояснять, что, конечно, в любой луже есть гад, между иными гадами иройский. [Михаил Веллер. Ножик Сережи Довлатова

Comment: Нашлось такое правило ("хотя" далее трактуется как подчинительный союз):
http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_188
1. При последовательном подчинении рядом могут оказаться подчинительные союзы (ЧТО и ЕСЛИ, ЧТО и КОГДА и др.). Запятая между ними ставится только в том случае, когда далее в предложении нет соотносительных слов ТО или ТОГДА.

Comment: 2.Если в сложном предложении рядом оказались сочинительный и подчинительный союзы (И и ХОТЯ, И и КАК и др.), то нужно выяснить, нет ли после придаточной части соотносительных слов ТО, ТАК или еще одного сочинительного союза (А, НО, ОДНАКО и др.). Запятая ставится только тогда, когда эти слова после придаточной части отсутствуют.

Comment: Alex_ander, "Грамота" - не тот источник, которому можно верить как самодостаточному. Ссылки они не дали.. Но дело не только в этом. Там первой строчкой:   

>В сложных предложениях, состоящих из трех или более предикативных частей,  

Чего-то не вижу я у себя трех частей...)))
(+)
В принципе, наверное, да, вы (мы) должно быть на верном пути... Но формулировку надо бы найти внятную и желательно на уровне (условного) Розенталя.

Comment: http://www.e-reading.link/chapter.php/48854/55/Rozental%27_-_Spravochnik_po_russkomu_yazyku._Punktuaciya.html

§ 36. Запятая на стыке двух союзов

... при «встрече» двух подчинительных союзов (или подчинительного союза и союзного слова) запятая между ними ставится, если изъятие второй придаточной части не требует перестройки главной части (практически — если дальше не следует вторая часть двойного союза то, так или но, наличие которой требует такой перестройки), и не ставится, если дальше следует указанная вторая часть двойного союза.

Answer (score 1):

behemothus, вы сами привели правило, на основании которого запятая не ставится.

> В начале предложения не разделяются запятой сочинительный и подчинительный союзы, а также подчинительный союз и союзное слово: ***Потому что где же они теперь могут встретиться? (Бун.).( Согласно ПАСУ).***

Comment: Не тот случай. Было бы слишком просто.   
Здесь вроде как союзы относятся к разным предложениям, поэтому запятая вроде бы ложна ставится просто по мотивам выделения придаточной части.   
  
Уберите "то" и запятая станет если не очевидной, то возможной.   
***"Хотя, если подумать, никто такого не утверждал".***       
***"Хотя, если я правильно его понял, он говорил с чужих слов".***       
  
В нацкорпусе полно примеров, включая примеры их классики (Довлатов и проч.) Не верб, что все они - по неграмотности.  
    
Серж, простите, вы как-то всегда очень прямолинейно подходите к правилам...

Comment:  behemothus, в вашем случае двойная часть часть союза. Хотя если... то. Поэтому запятая не нужна. Правило привели уже. Почему вы скептически относитесь к правилу? Грамота лишь изложила сконспектированное правило. То же правило изложено как у Розенталя, так и в ПАСЕ.